# How to create a table with slices in columns

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a model that looks like this:

```
type Inventory struct {
    gorm.Model
    LocationID string
    Items      []Item //this is a slice of structs
    Categories []Category //this is a slice of structs
}
```

When I create a table for it using gorm, I don't have the columns for Items or Categories. 
[image]
What am i missing?

Comment: Check if there any separate mapping table created in your db.

Comment: Slices cannot be natively stored in a database, so it makes sense that GORM skips them during table creation. I expect using a type that satisfies the [`driver.Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface would change GORM's behavior, but this is a guess (thus a comment, and not an answer).

Comment: If you can/want to use [pq](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq), it provides arrays for the most common types (`pq.StringArray`, `pq.ByteaArray` and more).

Answer (score 2):

Since arrays are not supported column types in SQL—most versions of SQL at least—gorm will not create columns for fields of type slice.

You can, however, create the relationship structure you are after using an association. In this case either the [has-many](http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#has-many) or [many-to-many](http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#many-to-many) would be appropriate (I can't tell from this example, though likely has-many).

These work by creating separate tables for these nested objects. In the has-many relationship, a separate table for items and categories would be created, each with a foreign key reference to the inventory table. The many-to-many case is similar but uses a join table rather than a simple foreign key.

For example (with has-many):

```
type Inventory struct {
    gorm.Model
    LocationID string
    Items      []Item //this is a slice of structs
    Categories []Category //this is a slice of structs
}

type Item struct {
    // ...
    InventoryId uint
}

type Category struct {
    // ...
    InventoryId uint
}

db.Model(&inventory).Related(&items)
db.Model(&inventory).Related(&categories)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @henry-woody wouldnt that just allow me to link the tables? i needed the indexes of the slices so i could tell the order. each location may have a different order of items and categories.

Comment: "*arrays are not supported column types in SQL*": JSON comes close; many SQL engines support it (PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL, MariaDB, etc.)

Comment: I think you can achieve that in two ways:
 - either store all Items and Categories with index values as a column and then sort them on fetch
 - If you have fixed items and categories.. maybe create a separate mapping table for Inventory - Items, Inventory - Categories and store each mapping with an index value, which u can use to sort or get the position.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the slice of objects in another table, as Henry suggested, is a good approach.
In my case, I wanted to store the slice of objects as a JSON array in the same table. Here's the solution I came up with, which might be helpful to someone else.

PostgreSQL already supports a `jsonb` type that can store JSON objects. First, we need to tell GORM to handle this field as a JSON object, which is done through tags:

```golang
type Inventory struct {
    gorm.Model
    LocationID string
    Items      []Item `gorm:"type:jsonb"`
}
```

Next, according to GORM [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html), for custom data types like `[]Item`, they need to implement Scanner/Valuer interfaces. Since `[]Item` is a slice and can't directly implement an interface, a workaround is to create an alias:

```golang
type Items []Item
```

Then, make `Items` implement the scanner/valuer interfaces like this:

```golang
func (c Items) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(c)
}

func (c *Items) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("Invalid data type for Items")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(bytes, &c)
}
```

Now, use the alias type in the `Inventory` struct:

```golang
type Inventory struct {
    gorm.Model
    LocationID string
    Items      Items `gorm:"type:jsonb"`
}
```

With this setup, the Scan/Value methods will be directly used when reading or writing this field.